# Why React choose not to adhere class pattern with ReactElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, factory-pattern

I am currently reading React source code. In most of the cases they prefer class pattern over factory function as constructor of instances.

Until I encounter `ReactElement`: [react/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b8cfda15e1232554487c7285fb464f22705a23ce/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L148)

The comment shows that they choose NOT to adhere class pattern here on purpose.

```js
/**
 * Factory method to create a new React element. This no longer adheres to
 * the class pattern, so do not use new to call it. Also, instanceof check
 * will not work. Instead test $$typeof field against Symbol.for('react.element') to check
 * if something is a React Element.
 *
 * @params omitted
 * ...
 */
const ReactElement = function(type, key, ref, self, source, owner, props) {
  // code omitted
}
```

But according to this comment, there are at least two obvious shortcomings,

1. User can not use `new ReactElement()` to instantiate element (the way they used to elsewhere).
2. `element instanceof ReactElement` no longer works.

I believe that they made that choice for a good reason, but just not listed in the comment. Anyone can give some explaination?

Comment: Since I'm not a React developer, I can only guess, but a plain object with a globally registered symbol is easy to serialise and e.g. send to a web worker.

Comment: No reason to use `class` if your objects don't have any methods. `ReactElement` is plain data.

Comment: Seems like it [never was intended to be a class](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c40e06f7281622a7a6295f4a7d5540a75fedf7bb/src/core/ReactDescriptor.js#L219-L226). (Updated [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/20e5a95fe31b790618edbbe6c4c9b026364bd36f) to the current wording). The [commit that changed it from a constructor function to a factory](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/750338ef4794af164d452d7560cb97a558c56d3c) indicates that this is a performance optimisation.

Comment: @Bergi really helpful references! Some interesting stories hidden in the commit history. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function just returns a plain object with `$$typeof: REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE`.  There's no need to make it a class constructor. I'd presume doing this is more optimizable by JS engines.

> User can not use new ReactElement() to instantiate element (the way they used to elsewhere).

React end-users never call this by themselves. They call `React.createElement()`.

> `element instanceof ReactElement` no longer works.

As an end user (c.f. a React internals developer), have you ever needed something like that? You'd be inspecting the internals of an JSX tree.

Comment: so just for performance reason?

Comment: After reading the references from @Bergi, I think I get your point now.